# Feedzirra with multiple feeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I've been using Feedzirra for a while to grab single feeds and parse them with no issues but I'm trying to run two separate feedburner feeds through it and I know that they work by themselves but running the both of them is producing an error.

```
NoMethodError in Feed entryController#index
undefined method `title' for #<Array:0x1042f9590>
```

My model looks like this:

```
def self.get_feeds
    feed_urls = ["feed_1", "feed_2"]
    update_from_feeds(feed_urls)
  end

  def self.update_from_feeds(feed_urls)
    feeds = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_urls)
    add_entries(feeds.entries)
  end

  def self.update_from_feeds_continuously(feed_urls, delay_interval = 30.seconds)
    feeds = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_urls)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
    loop do
      sleep delay_interval
      feeds = Feedzirra::Feed.update(feeds.entries)
      add_entries(feeds.new_entries) if feeds.updated?
    end
  end

  private

  def self.add_entries(entries)
    entries.each do |entry|
      unless exists? :guid => entry.id
        create!(
          :title        => entry.title
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

It's probably something I'm doing wrong but I can't find any full code examples or tutorials for parsing multiple feeds, just the two lines of code on the github page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `feeds` is returned in `update_from_feeds` from the `fetch_and_parse`, it is an array when multiple feeds are passed in. As such, the `each` in the `add_entries` method is splitting into individual feeds, not feed entries. To remedy this, you can redefine `update_from_feeds` as follows:

```
def self.update_from_feeds(feed_urls)
  feeds = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_urls)
  feeds.each do |feed_url, feed|
    add_entries(feed.entries)
  end
end
```

This assumes you will always be passing multiple feed url's to `update_from_feeds` (or a single url in an array)

Comment: This also means you need to modify `update_from_feeds_continuously` appropriately as well

Comment: Worked perfectly. I figured. Cheers for the help. I'm pretty new to Rails and Ruby, so thanks!